# NameError: name 'Daniel' is not defined when using input()

Tags: python

I'm brand new and am trying to make this incredibly basic code to work. When I run the code and type in my name, I get this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dbrown/Desktop/Name", line 2, in <module>
name= input()
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Daniel' is not defined
```

This is the original code:

```
print ("Please enter your name.")
name= input()
print ("Hello," , name)
```

Comment: The "original code" you posted works fine.  Maybe the code you're actually running is something else?

Comment: This code is fine, maybe you are using `Daniel` somewhere as a variable, I'm guessing you inputted `Daniel` and then used `Daniel` when you should be using `name`

Comment: The [mcve] is literally right there in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that this code was written for Python 3, but you're running it with Python 2.

In Python 2 you need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

The Python 2 version of `input` is

> Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.

(See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input.)

In other words, whatever you enter will be interpreted as Python code. In particular, something like `Daniel` will be looked up as a variable name. The `NameError` is thrown because there is no `Daniel` variable defined in your program.

Comment: Jeez, am I the only one upset by the fact they hid an `eval()` in a user input function like it's no big deal? The more I learn about Python the more I hate it.

Comment: @Havenard Solution: update to Python 3..

Comment: @user2864740 I think I'll stick to my solution, not use it at all.

Comment: @Havenard It's the Zonk of Python: Explicit is better than implicit, except when it comes to scoping and variable bindings, or when it's an implicit `eval()` on user input.

Comment: @Havenard Then please keep non-productive comments internal. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You are writing code for Python version 2, please consider changing to Python 3.

In python2, there's two console-input functions - `input()` and `raw_input()`.

`input()` is for reading integers, and `raw_input()` is for reading strings.  So under Python2, the following works:

```
print ("Please enter your name.")
name = raw_input()
print ("Hello, " + name)
```

Under Python 3, your code wortks fine already.

Your code is failing, because Python2 is trying to interpret "Daniel" as a python statement.

Answer (score 0):

Its because python 2, `raw_input` is python 3's `input`, and python 2's `input` is python 3's `eval(input(...))`, so basically just as here `Daniel` it tries to access that variable, but it's not defined so error is raised

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: @melpomene that's true, the explanation of this is only one way :-)